# how to get rid of id from checkbox and buttons and run through for?

Tags: javascript

How can I get rid of the set of id from buttons and checkbox?
I want to get rid of duplicate code. I tried to find the checkbox via const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
and iterate through "for" but I didn't succeed

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){};
```

here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/boL5qdex/7/

Comment: What do you mean by "how can i get rid of the set of id from buttons and checkbox?"

Comment: i want to get rid of duplicate code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way would be the following:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(el => {
  const btn = el.closest('label').nextElementSibling;

  el.addEventListener('change', evt => btn.disabled = !evt.target.checked);
});
```

```html
<label>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checkbox">
</label>
<button class="contcats__form-btn" id="form-send" type="submit">send 1</button>

<label>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checkbox-header">
</label>
<button class="modal__form-btn" id="header__form-send" type="submit">send 2</button>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checkbox-price">
</label>
<button class="modal__form-btn" id="price__form-send" type="submit">send 3</button>
```

---

But note that:

```
const btn = el.closest('label').nextElementSibling;
```

is a *bit* error-prone, as it blindly tries to select the correct button by assuming it's always the `nextElementSibling`. This fails quite easily, for example if you change the html structure. There are better ways, but it's hard to say which one would fit your requirements.

So you might want to find a better html structure (or other method) to select the related button more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `for` or `map`:

```
const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'); 
  
  for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
    console.log("with for:", checkbox[i].checked)
  };
  
  [...checkbox].map(check => console.log("with map: ", check.checked))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0fgz1m4j/13/

Comment: how to ckecked through for?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?